# How to get rid of endless requests?

Tags: reactjs

please help with useCallback, how to call it so that useEffect does not send endless requests to the server? Now it sends endless requests, I know that useCallback is needed for this, but I don’t understand how to use it

```
// Get data
useEffect(() => {
    api.getTestLeagues()
    .then(data => setLeagues(data));

    api.getTestCountries()
    .then(data => setCountries(data));

    if(sidebars === null && leagues !== null && countries !== null) {
        onTest()
    }

}, [api, leagues, sidebars, countries, onTest]);
```

// The 'onTest' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 29) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the 'onTest' definition into its own useCallback() Hook

```
// test
const onTest = () => {
    const updateObj = {
        leagues: {
            title: "Мои лиги", 
            items: leagues
        },
        countries: {
            title: "Страны",
            items: countries
        }
    };

    setSidebars(updateObj);
};
```

Req:
[image]

Comment: What you want to use is componentDidMount. Here's how to use them using hooks: https://medium.com/@felippenardi/how-to-do-componentdidmount-with-react-hooks-553ba39d1571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to load data once, normally done with `componentDidMount`.

2 `useEffect` fired only once, running in parralel

```
useEffect(() => {
    api.getTestLeagues()
    .then(data => setSidebarItemsLeagues(data)); // for items 1 (not null)
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    api.getTestCountries()
    .then(data => setSidebarItemsCountries(data)); // for items 2 (not     null)
}, [])
```

`useEffect` running only on data changes

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(sidebars === null && leagues !== null && countries !== null) {
    const updateObj = {
      leagues: {
          title: "Мои лиги", 
          items: leagues
      },
      countries: {
          title: "Страны",
          items: countries
      }
    };

    setSidebars(updateObj);
  }
}, [leagues, countries]);
```

### Update

`api` defined earlier ...

const api = new Services();

of course changes on every render but **should not be taken as dependency** as it's always uses the same urls - they are not parametrized. No meaningful (affecting data) changes - don't care.

If `api` is not passed to rendered components (ref cange could force rerenderings) then **there is no need to take care about it**.

You can get rid of this definition by

```
useEffect(() => {
    new Service().getTestLeagues()
    .then(data => setSidebarItemsLeagues(data)); // for items 1 (not null)
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    new Service().getTestCountries()
    .then(data => setSidebarItemsCountries(data)); // for items 2 (not     null)
}, [])
```

Even if it looks as unnecessary duplicating instances **it can be more optimal** when component is frequently rerendered - like in open-close view changes.

Comment: Your answer does not include all values from the component scope that changes over time (`api`, `sidebars` and `onTest `) and that are used by the effects. Your code will reference stale values from previous renders. See the note in this section: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Comment: @xadm What you said makes sense but adding the dependencies is a good thing to do. React also mentions that with some warnings. We know that `api` is just a class that has two functions that will not change dynamically but for react it is just another variable.

Comment: **When needed** - like (every render changing) event handler fn reference causing rerendering - **not this case**.

Comment: I'm assuming (from yesterday question) that it's needed for build sidebar menu - **once fired**, normally done with `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping `onTest` with useCallback like this:

```
const onTest = useCallback(() => {
    const updateObj = {
        leagues: {
            title: "Мои лиги", 
            items: leagues
        },
        countries: {
            title: "Страны",
            items: countries
        }
    };

    setSidebars(updateObj);
},[]);
```

The second argument to `useCallback` is an array of dependencies similar to `useEffect`.

BTW this will memorize the function so that a new function doesn't get created on every render.

**update**

It is better to split the useEffect so that each useEffect just focuses on executing something when their dependencies are changed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    api.getTestLeagues()
    .then(data => setLeagues(data));

    api.getTestCountries()
    .then(data => setCountries(data));
}, [api]);

useEffect(() => {
    if(sidebars === null && leagues !== null && countries !== null) {
        onTest()
    } 
},[onTest, sidebars, leagues, countries])
```

When you send a request that changes the state and also use the same state as a dependency that'll again send a request(because the value of the state changes) it'll cause an infinite loop.

**update 2**

The issue might be with the `api` class instance because on every new render a new instance is created.

You said you were doing something like this `const api = new Services();` so wrap that with useMemo like this:

```
const api = useMemo(() => {
 return new Services();
})
```

Comment: How is `api` defined?

Comment: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'onTest' before initialization
https://i.imgur.com/KrzNW22.png

Comment: @reacter make sure that `onTest` is defined before calling it.

Comment: @reacter Move `onTest` above the `useEffect`

Comment: @reacter updated my answer and also it's better to split the `useEffect` so that you can get rid of the warnings.

Comment: Your updated answer does not include all values from the component scope that changes over time (`leagues` and `countries`) and that are used by the effect. Your code will reference stale values from previous renders. See the note in this section: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Comment: @adesurirey Yes that is why I'm suggesting to split the `useEffect` so that all the dependencies are covered without ignoring any of them. Anyway, I'll update the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're in an infinite loop because your effect depends on values you change in it: each time you fetch some data from the api you change `leagues` and `countries` states which leads to running the effect again.

Split the effects so that the requests effect does not depend on the values it changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  api.getTestLeagues().then(data => setLeagues(data));
  api.getTestCountries().then(data => setCountries(data));
}, [api]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(sidebars === null && leagues !== null && countries !== null) {
    onTest();
  }
}, [leagues, sidebars, countries, onTest]);
```

Also:

- Define `api` outside of your component (above) so the value stays stable.
- You can wrap `onTest` in a `useCallback` before your effects, like @Ramesh suggested.

Comment: weird, api may be changing, I'll update the code so you can memoize it

Comment: is `api` defined in the component? Instead of using `useMemo`, just define it above the component.